# Query to display from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am doing an late-to-work attendance system. So I have displayed the attendance details with the employee id(FK in table attendance, PK in table employee) and also the supervisor id(FK in table attendance and employee, PK in table supervisor) who supervised the employee using JOIN because I need to display the employee's name (from the table employee) as well. 
The output looks like this:

[OUTPUT](http://i1070.photobucket.com/albums/u482/teafortwo29/S_zpsf9c3856d.png)

And then there'll be a button that user needs to click which will link to the next page, which is to send the attendance report SMS to the supervisor.
I'm trying to JOIN three tables that displays

- the name of the supervisor (from table supervisor)

- supervisor phone number (from table supervisor)

- name of the employee. (from table employee)

This is the query that I have made but it only displays the first employee name (Max) even when I clicked on SEND SMS for Jane.

```
if (isset($_GET['supervisor_id'])) 
$supervisor_id = $_GET['supervisor_id'];
else
$supervisor_id=0;
include 'dbconnect.php';

$query = "SELECT s.supervisor_name, e.supervisor_id, s.supervisor_telno, e.employee_name 
 FROM supervisor s
  JOIN employee e, attendance a
 WHERE a.supervisor_id=e.supervisor_id=s.supervisor_id='".$supervisor_id."' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('SQL ERROR 2');
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Inner Joins to accomplish this, try this:

```
SELECT s.supervisor_name, e.supervisor_id, s.supervisor_telno, e.employee_name 
    FROM supervisor s
        INNERJOIN employee e on e.supervisor_id=s.supervisor_id
            INNER JOIN attendance a on a.supervisor_id=s.supervisor_id
```

Comment: Thank you Dan. I tried it but it still displays Max's name when I clicked for Jane's.